# Describing weather data in ArcMap area solar radiation analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, solar-radiation

I am writing up the methodology of the analysis I did on solar radiation availability for a city. I used the tool 'area solar radiation' with ArcMap 10, using the time configuration 'TimeWholeYear(2008)' and latitude 51.

Now I want to write a short paragraph about the weather data used in this analysis (i.e. type of data, data source, etc.) but I cannot find anything about it on the GIS help. Does anyone have any ideas of where to find a description of the weather data used in ArcMap?

Comment: As far as I know, this calculation does not use any weather data at all: see the documentation at http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/How_solar_radiation_is_calculated/009z000000tm000000/.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification! I guess I was confused by the fact that I could choose what year to perform the calculations for (in this case 2008), but now I see that it is probably just for the 'calendar' of the calculations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @whuber:

> As far as I know, this calculation does not use any weather data at
>   all: see the documentation at
>   http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/How_solar_radiation_is_calculated/009z000000tm000000/.